# PHP waits for the whole script to complete and combines all the echo together

Tags: php, apache, iis, flush, output-buffering

I have a PHP code as below. When I run this on Apache (Apache/2.2.17 ), the result is that it prints '**Program started....**' and then waits for 5 seconds and then print 'Script complete.' when I run this on a browser.

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(TRUE);

echo 'Program started....';
ob_flush();

sleep(5);//making the script to wait for 5 seconds

echo 'Script complete.';

?>
```

When I run the same above code on IIS (IIS 8), I program waits for 5 seconds and then prints 'Program started....Script complete.' at the end of execution.

How can I make the code to behave the same on IIS as i does on Apache.

Comment: Check the output buffering value E.G: `output_buffering = 4096` in `php.ini` for differences. Use `echo 'Program started....<br>';`

Comment: output_buffering = 4096 in both Apache and IIS. 
Using 'Program started....<br>' in echo did not help as well.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the PHP documentation for flush note several items in apache to check that may prevent flush() working properly:

> Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own
>   that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately
>   to the client.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php and do a find for "apache" for items to try disabling. Example from commenter mandor at mandor dot net:

> This is what I use to turn off pretty much anything that could cause
>   unwanted output buffering and turn on implicit flush:
>
> `@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
> @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
> @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
> for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
> ob_implicit_flush(1);`
>
>   
>   ?>